# assigning a cost to nodes in A Star

Tags: c++

At the moment I am trying to work out the A Star Pathfinding Algorithm.

Where I'm stuck is the following:

1. Assigning a 'Cost' to each node - I have a text file of a 10x10 array, in the array each 'node' has a cost of 0,1,2 or 3, this is how I'm reading it in:

   ```
   void map()                                                  
   {
       vector<string> mArray;   
       int row = 10;
       int col = 10;

   ifstream inFile("dMap.txt");                             


       string line;                                            
       while (getline(inFile, line))
       {
           mArray.push_back(line);                             
       }

       while (inFile && row <= 100)
       {
           inFile >> mArray[row][col];
           if (inFile)
           {
               if (++col == 10)
               {
                   ++row;
                   col = 0;
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```

The next issue I have:

2. I need to compare the nodes around the 'Current' Node, now, I can push the starting node and current to a list, I assume I then compare current/next to the already visited list and then I want the one with the lowest score (cost + manhattan distance) however, the way I've implemented it seems to ignore those nodes completely:

   ```
       startNode -> x = 4;
       startNode -> y = 4;
       startNode -> cost = 0;
       endNode -> x = 8;
       endNode -> y = 8;

   openList.push_front(move(startNode));

   while (currentNode ->x == endNode->x || currentNode->y == endNode->y)// This is the same result if I change it to !openList.empty()
   {
       currentNode = move(openList.front());
       openList.pop_front();   

       if (openList.empty())
       {
           cout << "Failure" << endl;
           return 0;
       }
       //north Node
       currentNode.reset(new coords);
       currentNode -> x + 1;
       currentNode -> y;
       currentNode->cost + 1;
       openList.push_front(move(currentNode));
    if (currentNode == endNode)
   {
       cout << "Goal Found" <<endl;
       cout << openList.front()->x << " " << openList.front()->y << endl;
   }   


   }
   ```

I know its moving start and current to the openlist as the debugging does tell me and when i outputted this part the start and current nodes were there just fine, it was the rest of it that was missing

Comment: A\* requires a heuristic for each node that determines the estimated combined cost to the goal. You don't seem to evaluate that at all, turning this basically into [Dijkstra's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra's_algorithm). At any rate, what is your **specific** issue?

Comment: My specific issue is giving each node a cost of either 0, 1, 2 or 3 and then adding a heuristic to that (so I can compare nodes with their neighbors)

Comment: Costs aren't assigned to nodes. Costs are assigned to vertices. They model how expensive it is to travel from one node to another. If you try to assign costs to nodes, then this is an error, and you need to re-think your problem.

Comment: Yea, that's more accurate to what I meant, how do I do that part? I'm struggling to explain where I'm going wrong, that's my biggest problem

Comment: You cannot store the costs in an array identical to your nodes array. Assuming a cartesian grid of nodes, where each neighboring node can be reached, you'll have to store a data structure comprising costs for all 8 directions (horizontal, vertical, and diagonal). More generally, for each node you have to store costs for all paths leading to another node.

Comment: Ah ok, so (I have 4 directions not 8) so I'd have a class that declares that as a grid with different varibles like bool water = 3, bool wall =0 etc?

Comment: I'd rather assign each node an array of size 4, storing the costs for all 4 directions. That way you can simply run a loop over the array and expand nodes (including their costs) to be added to the *open* list. The *open* list could be modeled as a *priority queue*, sorted by accumulated costs plus heuristic, in ascending order. The front of the queue is then the next node to expand.

Comment: Ok, that sounds more reasonable to do (especially if a map adds more obstacles as well) I now need to work out how to do that part